# I don't know why my linked list pointer isnt moving

Tags: c, printf, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a piece of code that adds elements to a list.

```
typedef struct things {
    int value;
    struct things *next;
} something;


int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    something *head = NULL;
    something *current = NULL;
    current = head; //current points to head address
    while(input != -1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        while(current != NULL) //loop until current node returns NULL
        {
            current = current->next; //go to next node
        }

        current = malloc(sizeof(something)); //allocate memory for new node assuming current is NULL
        current->value = input;
        current->next = NULL; //next points to NULL
    }
    current=head; //current points back to head
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    puts("NULL");

    return 0;
}
```

when i try to print through the list however, i get no output. So even if i input 1 2 3 4..etc the print function doesnt output anything

```
while(current != NULL)
{
    printf("%d -> ", current->value);
    current = current->next;
}
puts("NULL");
```

I'm expecting an output like  `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... 9 -> NULL`. I've just started learning about linked lists so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `current = malloc(sizeof(something));` You never connect this new node to the end of the list or even if it is the first node set the head pointer.

Comment: Your loop before the malloc is a waste of time since all you do is reassign current to the return of malloc.  What you actually need is a pointer to a pointer, then you return the address of 'next' and assign it with *current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't at any point update the value of `head`. Or point the last node in the list to the newly created one.

Check to see if `head` is set first and if not, populate it. Otherwise, find the last node of the list and add the new to as the "next" one from it like below.

```
if(head == NULL)
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(something));
    head->value = input;
    head->next = NULL; //next points to NULL
}
else
{
    current = head;
    while(current->next != NULL) //loop until current node returns NULL
    {
        current = current->next; //go to next node
    }

    current->next = malloc(sizeof(something)); //allocate memory for new node assuming current is NULL
    current->next->value = input;
    current->next->next = NULL; //next points to NULL
}
```

Comment: Since the code repeatedly adds to the end of the list, it would be possible to set `current` to `head` in the `if (head == NULL)` branch, and then simply use that to add the next node without any need to search for the tail of the list (add `current = current->next;` at an appropriate point in the assignments (just after the `malloc()` is checked?) and if necessary, modify the other assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach is not suited for single pointer.
Where allocating memory to `current` won't insert the node to list.

By just making `current` as pointer to pointer as below your approach will work.

```
int input = 0;
something *head = NULL;
something **current = NULL;
current = &head; //current points to head address
while(input != -1)
{
    scanf("%d", &input);
    while(*current != NULL) //loop until current node returns NULL
    {
        current = &(*current)->next; //go to next node
    }

    *current = malloc(sizeof(something)); //allocate memory for new node assuming current is NULL
    (*current)->value = input;
    (*current)->next = NULL; //next points to NULL
}
current=&head; //current points back to head
while(*current != NULL)
{
    printf("%d -> ", (*current)->value);
    current = &(*current)->next;
}
puts("NULL");
```

Comment: That's a powerful technique; I'm not sure it is how I'd teach list processing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree. I just went along with OP approach. I mean How to make his approach work.